# Recursive functions and lists appending/extending

Tags: python, list, function, recursion, extend

This is a very simple code in place of a bigger problem, but I'm hoping I can tackle it in chunks. I'll start with my first problem.

```
def testrecurse(z,target):
    x=[]
    if z<target:
        z*=2
        x.append(z)
        x.extend(testrecurse(z,target))
    return x
```

This is a test function to help my brain out with recursion. It takes a number, then shows all the multiplications of two until it hits the target number. so if I enter:

```
testrecurse(1,1000)
```

I receive:

```
[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
```

which is great! Output looks good and clean. But here's my problem, I'm having a hard time appending or adding that very first value, in my output. Here's what I want the output to look like.

```
[1,2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
```

I've tried changing

```
x=[] to x=[z]
```

but then I receive:

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16, 32, 32, 64, 64, 128, 128, 256, 256, 512, 512, 1024, 1024]
```

any help would be appreciated, I'm new to recursion and it makes my head hurt.

Comment: Try appending before multiplying with 2, and changing `if z<target` to use <= instead.

Comment: Oh, thank you for this, I didn't realize a simple change like that would fix it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about this?

```
def testrecurse(z, target):
    if z >= target:
        return []
    return [z] + testrecurse(2 * z, target)
```

Example:

```
>>> testrecurse(1, 1000)
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
```

Note that it does not include `1024` any more.  If you want this, change the third line to

```
        return [z]
```

Of course you wouldn't normally write this recursively, but rather use a `for` loop or `itertools.takewhile()`.

Comment: You know what, I never thought of concatenating the list, thank you very much for this, I think it'll help alot.

Comment: you sir, deserve more likes than you have