# How can I search the value of a key on a recursive dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I had written a recursive function to find a value with given `dict` and `key`.
But I think there should be a more readable version. Here is the code block.

```
def findvalue(_dict, target):
    for key, values in _dict.items():
        if 'dict' in str(type(values)):
            return findvalue(values, target)
        elif key == target:
            return values
        else:
            print("no such key")
```

Is there any one line version of this or using yield(not sure about this)?

**Edit**: Based on [Recursive functions and lists appending/extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896951/recursive-functions-and-lists-appending-extending) and ideas from comments I modified the function to find all matched values by the given key

```
def find_all_value(_dict, target, values=None):
    for key, values in _dict.items():
        #case 1: it is a dictionary but not match the key
        if isinstance(values, dict) and key!=target:
            return find_all_value(values, target)
        #case 2: it is a dictionary but match the key -> put it in result
        elif isinstance(values, dict) and key==target:
            return [values] + find_all_value(values, target)
        #case 3: it is not dictionary and match the key -> put it in result
        elif key==target:
            return [values]
```

Comment: I don't think your code works. You're searching for the literal string value `'dict'` in the `str(type())` of `values`.. So you're basically doing `if 'dict' in '<class 'list'>'` which I'm sure is not what you want.

Comment: The first "if" uses for checking if it is a dictionary type.
If it is not a dictionary, then it will check for key==target, if true, then return the value(can be any type except dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##Edit:##
***Recursive search for (nested) dict(s) via list comprehension:***

```
def findvalue(d, key):

    l = [e for e in [findvalue(e, key) for e in [d[k] for k in d.keys() if type(d[k])==dict]] if e]
    l.append(d[key]) if key in d else l
    return l
```

*^ Returns (nested) lists of values for each matching (nested) dict key.*

***Simplified version which prints, instead of returning, each match:***

```
def findvalue(d, key):

    [findvalue(e, key) for e in [d[k] for k in d.keys() if type(d[k])==dict]]
    if key in d: print(d[key])
```

*^ Just displays the values, for each matching key, as they
are encountered.*

***Test with:***

```
d = {1:2, 3:4, 5:{6:7,8:9, 99:{100:101}}, 10:11}
```

Comment: This one looks good but only can handle 1 depth situation. If it can check a nested dictionary then it will be better

Comment: @PoonKingSing Updated: Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 2):

To find the value of the first key (found in Breadth First Search) of a recursive python dictionnary.

You can do:

```
def find_value(_dict, key):
    stack = [(None, _dict)]
    while len(stack) != 0:
        _key, val = stack.pop(0)
        if val is not _dict and _key == key:
            return val
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            for k, v in val.items():
                stack.append((k, v))
```

Example:

```
d = {'c': {'d': 3, 'e': 4}, None: 0, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}

print('None:', find_value(d, None))
print('c:', find_value(d, 'c'))
print('e:', find_value(d, 'e'))
print('a:', find_value(d, 'a'))
```

Output:

```
None: 0
c: {'e': 4, 'd': 3}
e: 4
a: 1
```

Comment: It is a more complete version which also handle return the value if the key is a dictionary.